# Python: universal import

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

Can anyone explain which 'import' is universal, so I don't need to write for example:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import *
```

Why not `import numpy` or `from numpy import *` to incude all from "numpy"?

Comment: What do you mean by "universal"?

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: I dont understand why I need to write > from numpy.linalg import *' if I already declared 'from numpy import *'

Comment: Convenience. It just means you can refer directly to those variables, rather than referring to them as `linalg.whatever`. Also, `from pkg import *` doesn't necessarily bring in everything from the package - the package author can specify an `__all__` variable to indicate which objects to load.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit so that the question remains visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "all from numpy", but you should never need to use more than one form of `import` at a time. They do different things:

### Option One: `import`

`import numpy` will bring the entire numpy module into the current namespace. You can then reference anything from that moudule as `numpy.dot` or `numpy.linalg.eig`.

### Option Two: `from ... import *`

`from numpy import *` will bring all of the public objects from numpy into the current namespace as local references. If the package contains a list named `__all__` then this command will also `import` every sub-module defined in that list.

For numpy this list includes 'linalg', 'fft', 'random', 'ctypeslib', 'ma', and  'doc' last I checked. So, once you've run this command, you can call `dot` or `linalg.eig` without the numpy prefix.

If you're looking for an import that will pull every symbol from every submodule in the package into your namespace, then I don't think there is one. You would have to do something like this:

```
from numpy.linalg import *
from numpy.fft import *
from numpy.random import *
from numpy.ctypeslib import *
from numpy.ma import *
from numpy import *
```

which is, I think, what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Although there isn't one for a fairly good reason: if a load of objects turn up in your namespace from different modules, it's much harder to work out where each one comes from when you read the code. `from x import *` is best used in moderation.

Comment: For third party modules that aren't explicitly designed to be used that way, `from x import *` is best avoided everywhere other than the interactive prompt.